# JSON strange parse error in Android app

Tags: android, json

I would like to ask one question about JSON parsing.

Right now I am getting response that looks like this:

```
{"resultCode":200,"resultContent":{"orderId":"1268"}}
```

So, as far as I know this is one int value and one array with one record. In ma app I am extracting those values this way:

```
int id = -1;
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(json);
int resultCode = jObject.getInt(RESULT_CODE);
if (resultCode!=200) {
    return id;
}
JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray(RESULT_CONTENT);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jArrayObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    id = Integer.valueOf(jArrayObject.getString(ORDER_ID));
}
return id;
```

So, it should work, and id should have the proper value.

However, I am getting an error/warning that is saying:

> org.json.JSONException: Value {"orderId":"1268"} at resultContent of
>   type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

My question is, what am I doing wrong here, and how it can be repaired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`resultContent` isn't an `JSONArray`, it's just a `JSONObject`.

As a tip, `JSONArray`s are recognizable because they have square brackets ("[","]").

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I've been still confusing with this.

Answer (score 0):

`resultContent` is an Object, no an array. Change it for `JSONObject jArray = jObject.getJSONObject(RESULT_CONTENT);`

Comment: And while you're at it, you could try GSON, its a library from Google that'll de-serialize Json to a pojo (class) object

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/